# × Encountered error while trying to install package in heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to deploy a dash application on heroku and It is showing " × Encountered error while trying to install package remote:numpy" and error: failed to push some"
I tried changing the version of numpy in my requirment.txt file but the system seems to install older version of numpy and the same error occur. I am also getting errors while pushing to the master branch, so I created a new branch named "masterbranch" and pushed on it, but the build was skipped. I am using "git push heroku branchmaster:master" for building the app and it is being rejected constantly with the mentioned error. Thank you .

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/okncc.png

Answer (score 3):

I solved the error. There was probelem with the requirement file. Some Dependencies were required to install numpy so I added them in my requirement.txt file and the error was resoved. Initially my requirement contain thses files:

[Initially my requirement contain these packages:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfCiG.png)

[After adding necessary dependencies and modifying the some versions:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VgZd.png)
P.S i am no expert But This method work for me and I hope it won't hurt any body to share.